# Jquery Clone, Changed value is not persist on the cloned object (div)

Tags: jquery

Need your help regarding to the Jquery that I'm currently working. I have to clone a div but before I clone the div, I need to do some modification like Ajax call to know the value then clone. In my code below, I was able to clone BUT the question is why my changes not persist on the cloned div. I'm still getting the Value3 on the cloned DIV

You may check the below snippet

```
<div id="container">
<select id="ddl">
  <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
  <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
  <option value="Value3" selected>Value3</option>
  <option value="Value4">Value4</option>
</select>

</div>
<div id="clonecontainer">
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

var div = $('#container');
    var msg = $(div).find('#ddl :selected');
     //ajax call for example change Value4 to Value1
    $(msg).val("Value1");
    alert($(msg).val());
    var tr = $(div).clone(true);
    $(tr).appendTo("#clonecontainer");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/og2vu5a4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is value attribute in html ? It's only alerting static value
change your html to

```
<div id="container">
<select id="ddl">
    <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="Value3" selected>Value3</option>
    <option value="Value4">Value4</option>
</select>

</div>
<div id="clonecontainer"></div>
```

and try this js and with this code ->$(msg).val("Value1"); you are changing selected options value. Are you doing it deliberately.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var div = $('#container select');
var msg = $(div).find('option:selected');

//$(msg).val("Value1");
alert($(msg).val());
var tr = $(div).clone(true, true);
$(tr).appendTo("#clonecontainer");
var msg2 = $('#clonecontainer select');
var values="Value1"
$('#clonecontainer select').val(values);
```

Here is your fiddle
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/og2vu5a4/5/)

Comment: Hi, I have to do some ajax call or logic before I clone.

Comment: and you want to change selected option after that ajax

Comment: Yes, I need to change that :)

Comment: can you look now and tell me if you found your answer ?